# Alert doesn't close using Selenium WebDriver with Google Chrome.

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following Selenium script for opening alert on rediff.com:

```java
public class TestC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin_info']/a[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_login")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
}
```

This very same script is working fine in Firefox and IE9, however using Google Chrome after opening the alert, rest of the code is not working. The main thing is that does not shows any exception, error or anything.

Please provide any solution as soon as possible.
Thanks a lot!

Note: If we need to change any setting of browser or any thing please let me know.

```
Selenium version:Selenium(2) Webdriver
OS:Windows 7
Browser:Chrome
Browser version:26.0.1410.64 m
```

Comment: Which version of chromedriver.exe are you using? If you're using chromedriver2, I don't believe alert handling works with Chrome 26.

Comment: Yup..i had sorted my problem using driver change. Now alert is closed very well in my script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your problem is a very common one, that's why i never advise using `Thread.sleep()`, since it does not guarantee the code will run only when the `Alert` shows up, also it may add up time to your tests even when the alert is shown.

The code below should wait only until some alert is display on the page, and i'd advise you using this one Firefox and IE9 aswell.

```java
public class TestC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();   
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

        driver.get("http://www.rediff.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='signin_info']/a[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("btn_login")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
}
```

Mostly all that is done here, is changing `Thread.sleep()`, for a condition that actually will only move forward on the code as soon a `alert()` is present in the page. As soon as someone does, it wil switch to it and accept.

You can find the Javadoc for the whole `ExpectedConditions` class [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AlertIsPresent doesn't exist in C# API
http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

You can use something like this:

```
private static bool TryToAcceptAlert(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    try
    {
        var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
        alert.Accept();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}


public static void AcceptAlert(this IWebDriver driver, int timeOutInSeconds = ElementTimeout)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOutInSeconds)).Until(
        delegate { return driver.TryToAcceptAlert(); }
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i am using java that's way i find AlertIsPresent method.