# Selenium - Accepting the Confirmation dialog box working fine in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Did any one has overcome the issue below?

I have a confirmation dialog box after hitting a submit button. When I use `driver.switch().alert().accept()` for the Firefox driver, I'm not seeing any issue. But when I use the same script for the Chrome driver, nothing happens. Could you please suggest how to resolve this issue?

I have tried the `getWindowHandle()` method, but that also didn't work.

Why is it working for Firefox, but not for Chrome?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, my Chrome 30 correctly accepts all kinds of JS modal dialogs. Do you have a reproducible testcase you could show us?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437911/alert-doesnt-close-using-selenium-webdriver-with-google-chrome

Comment: Thanks Slanec for the quick response, I could able to reproduce. Below is the error message

Comment: Hi Patwary, I tried with Wait also. but that also didn't worked. any other suggestion?? I'm using CHROME 28. The same script working fine in FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

When Working with Alert, i guess its better to use "try/Catch" though it isnt the conventional. I had the same issue with IE. Alert handling was ok with Firefox but failed in IE. You could do something this way

```
try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String AlertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println(AlertText);
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no alert")
    }
```

Something like above.

**UPDATED**

```
public void aLert() {
    boolean a = false;
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String AlertText = alert.getText();
        System.out.println(AlertText);
        alert.accept();
        a = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        a = false;
    }finally {
        if (a != true) {
            // take ur screenshot or whatever
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath(//xpath of the ok button or accept button)click();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No, its not working. The Script execution stops after getting the confirmation window. I tried in Debug mode, the script is not going to the next line if i press F6. But when click Ok/Cancel button in the confirmation window, the script start executes. Any idea?

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan : I guess the Alertbox is not recognized. Try checking the presence of Alertbox in the code. What i have given above is a sample on how to do it.(actually it should work). I have updated the answer to check the presence of Alertbox. Give it a shot and let us know.

Comment: Hi Sriram, Thanks for helping me out. I'm very new to selenium. Could you please help me how to find the xpath for the Confirmation pop up. Its a modal dialog box. I couldn't able to do anything.

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan : If u are new, learning how to frame xpath or Css is essential. There are many sites/materials online which provide essential informations on those. Since you are new to selenium, apart from xpath there are other ways of identifying elements. For Ex : id,tagname etc. Now to answer your question, if u are using firefox there is something called firebug and firepath (both are addons). You can use the above to get the firepath of the element. For chrome, once you open the browser and your application, press F12. The console module opens.

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan : At the left bottom. U will have a search symbol. Click that(its for selecting an element). Now when u hover yourmouse over the ok/accept button, u can see it getting highlighted.Click the ok/accept button. Now in the console u can see the html snippet of the element getting highlighted. Right click on the HTML and select "copy xpath". Bingo!! U have your xpath now.

Comment: @sriram.. i'm using Firebug to identify the XPATH.. As this is the modal dialog box how i will use the firebug to identify the element. ?????

Comment: @VenkateshLakshmanan : The regular way. I mean how you identify other elements. Firebug identifies elements for alerts/modal dialog box as well.