# How to get title of page in Chrome browser when an alert in opened on the same page using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In **CHROME** window, There is an alert opened. But without closing the alert first, is there any way to get window title of the page. Because When i try

driver.getTitle();

without closing the alert 
Exception occurs : unexpected alert open.

Reason i want to very file page title is because there are multiple windows opened, & i wish to close alert only on particular page. I used the below code for switching to that window

```
for (String winhandle :driver.getWindowHandles())       
{

   driver.switchTo().window(winhandle); 

if (driver.getTitle().equals("some_title")) 
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());           
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.close();
}   

}
```

**NOTE : above mentioned same code works fine with FIREFOX. Issue occurs only with the chrome browser**

Comment: Is the alert opens immediately after the new page or tab is opened?

Comment: This might just solve  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852732/selenium-webdriver-how-to-close-browser-popup

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437911/alert-doesnt-close-using-selenium-webdriver-with-google-chrome

Comment: @k.s Karthik -Yes button on current window is clicked, a new window is opened & it has a popup in it.

Comment: @user1570408 Thanks! Yes i have visited these links, but these don't resolve the issues.

Comment: Can you even switch tabs programmatically when an alert is up? I can't manually. I don't think you can have more than one alert up at a time. Are you consfusing javascript alerts with dialogs and/or other browser windows?

Comment: these are different browser windows not the tab in one browser window. Yes i am able to switch between the windows programmatically . The code i mentioned above works well with firefox. Its a simple Confirmation alert with ok & dismiss button popped inside a new browser window.